# Route resource in route group with prefix in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I'm trying to create a route resource in a route group:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth'], 'prefix' => 'template'], function() {
    Route::resource('template', 'TemplateController');

    Route::get('{template}/assign', 'blabla');
    Route::post('{template}/assign', 'blabla');

    Route::get('{template}/clone', 'blabla');
    Route::get('{template}/customizer', 'blabla');
});
```

But now I get routes like this: `template.template.index`, `template.template.create`, etc.

And when I change the name **from** `Route::resource('template', 'TemplateController');` **to** `Route::resource('/', 'TemplateController');`, the route look like this: `template..index`, `template..create`, etc.

I do have a solution but then I need to create another route group without prefix.

**(TL;DR;)** I was wondering how to make the route resource work in a route group with prefix and have the correct route name (template.index, template.create, etc.).

Comment: Just checking - Did my answer help at all or have you fixed your issue yourself?

Comment: I used my old solution. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `as` to define the route name. You can also use it in groups:

```
Route::group(['as' => 'admin::'], function () {
    Route::get('dashboard', ['as' => 'dashboard', function () {
        // Route named "admin::dashboard"
    }]);
});
```

I assume you are using Laravel 5.1+ seeing as you are using group prefixes. You can read more in the route section of Laravel:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#named-routes

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#named-routes

Not sure how you should do it in your case (my best guess would be to leave the `as` empty in the group), so you're going to have to fiddle around. But the principle should be the same.

**(My best guess):**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth'], 'prefix' => 'template', 'as' => ''], function() {
    // stuff
});
```

If naming the group does not work in your case, you may have to set the `as` for each route.